# Network issues with sql server

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, network

There are two servers on co-location. First is Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 SP1. Second is Windows Server 2012 + Sql Server Standard 2012 SP1.

First server has a task with a report against tables in Server B. Report runs via sqlcmd11. Normally, it takes 3-4 seconds. But sometimes it hangs in the middle of data receiving (even, If I redirect output to console) and around at 20 seconds after start connection is killed with these errors:

```
HResult 0x2746, Level 0, State 10
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

HResult 0x2746, Level 0, State 0
Communication link failure

Network packet size (bytes): 4096
1 xact[s]:
Clock Time (ms.): total     21107  avg   21107.00 (0.05 xacts per sec.)
```

Sqlcmd runs script from file. Command line is:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S "ip,port"
    -U username -P password -u -i script.sql -o output.html -m-1 -p
```

Query has header:

```
declare @today datetime = cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
declare @yesterday datetime = dateadd(day, -1, @today)
declare @days15 datetime = dateadd(day, -15, @today)
declare @days10 datetime = dateadd(day, -10, @today)
```

Then is contains 5 pairs:

```
print N'Report header'
select <report body>
```

Queries doesn't use table variables or any temp table. I read about tcp chimney and other tcp options. Disabling them on both sides didn't help.

Sql Server logs don't have messages about killing my process.

Comment: could you post what does sqlcmd do exactly? does it generate text output or staging tables?  what is the "report"?

Comment: @Rohan, I updated post just now.

Comment: Just to debug, can you try the following, run the sqlcmd on the SQL Server itself (ServerB) and check for the error, also try using osql (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx)

Comment: Results: sqlcmd on server B ran report for 3-4 seconds almost in all time, one time it hangs for 5 seconds and finished report at 10 seconds. osql results didn't differ from sqlcmd. Actually, we are moving from osql to sqlcmd/powershell, because osql is deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, that leads to a lot more questions, what is the kind of load on the SQL Server? run "netstat -ano" in cmd, how many rows do you see? when the report takes a long time (10 seconds) is it being blocked (log sys.processes continuously)? There are also lot of other things that can cause that generic error (for example, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/b7a4c6f2-0d1b-44ba-bb55-0e7848d64198/)

Comment: Rohan, my main question - why connection is killed :) Main load to sql server is OLTP, around 100 batches per seconds, most read-only transactions have snapshot isolation. netstat shows 101 active connection. EventLog shows continous restarting of Windows Installer, looks like this: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/770630/msiexec-exe-processes-keep-running-after-installation-of-sql-server-2012-sp1

Comment: Are the servers virtualized or physical? Are the network adapters configured to use large packets? Is the switch and/or virtual switch configured to allow the use of large packets? This seems more like a network issue than a SQL Server issue.

Comment: Servers are physical. How large are "large packets"? 4k? I don't have any access or control of switches or routers in network. And it seems I resolved issue. Report script has "use dbname" directive in first line. If I add "go" on second line, all works perfectly. I can't understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[Can't add comments yet so "commenting" here and a moderator can change it to a comment.]

I would recommend checking the network adapter properties on all systems involved and disabling auto-detect network speed/duplex.  If it's set to auto-detect and you don't want to change it without knowing it's causing a problem, copy some large files and see if you're getting the expected throughput.  If not, auto-detect has probably not negotiated the correct speed an duplex and this will cause poor throughput and flaky connections.  I used to do tech support for a data replication co. and we fixed so many connection stability and throughput issues with this it's not even funny.